# If Git Stash saves Diffs, then why can't it be applied to a different branch?

Tags: git

As I understand it, Git Stash is a collection of diffs.

So for example, if I have a whole repo with a single file `foo.txt`

The 32 lines of the file is just

```
Lorem Ipsum 01
Lorem Ipsum 02
Lorem Ipsum 03
...
Lorem Ipsum 30
a first line: good
a second line: bad
```

And I committed everything.

Now I create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b feature123
```

And now that I am on this branch, I change the word `good` to `better`, and `bad` to `worse`.

Now, just suppose my program manager comes over and say, "Urgent! We have to change the 01 to 011 and 02 to 022".

So I stash the changes, and then change to the `master` branch:

```
git stash
git checkout master
```

and I changed the `01` to `011`, and `02` to `022` as he requested.

And say, I want to incorporate the changes that I "stashed" earlier to the `master` branch:

```
git stash apply
```

but it will error out:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    foo.txt
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Why is that?  Can't it just apply the collection of diffs to `foo.txt`?

(P.S. I can commit first, and then use `git stash apply`, and be able to apply those diffs to `foo.txt`.  But why not before the commit?  So `git stash` really just saves a collection of diffs -- to repeat precisely: a collection of diffs, and then do a `git checkout .` (to abandon all changes).  Is that true?)

Comment: Did you commit the changes you made before attempting to apply the stash'd changes?

Comment: @sisyphus The question is why the changes need to be commited (or stashed), and why `git stash` can't `apply` patches to changed files.

Comment: It's a safety mechanism, I for one am very glad it won't just overwrite my changes, w/o at least having me stage them.

Comment: *[...] Git Stash is a collection of diffs.* The premise of the question is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

> Git Stash is a collection of diffs.

Not really. a stash is a collection of commit objects, each of them records a complete snapshot of the project. `git stash pop` does a merge between the current head, the stash, and the commit the stash is based on.

It would be possible in theory to perform a merge on locally-modified files, but in practice:

- This would be a really bad idea for `merge` because it would encourage users to do "evil merges", i.e. have both merge-related an manual changes in the same commit. As a consequence, it is forbidden for a merge to touch locally modified files, and `stash` uses the same mechanism as `merge`, hence forbids it the same way.
- The index makes things more complex than they appear to be. If a file had unstaged content, and you wanted to apply a stash to it, then there would be no proper way to define what should be the content of the index at the end of the stash application. Actually, `stash pop` is allowed to touch files for which the index matches the working tree.

Note: your problem is not the fact that you are on different branches, but that you have uncommited/unstaged changes. You did these changes while on branch `feature123`, but they are preserved when switching branches with `git checkout master`.

Comment: say if my change is 1 character in 1 file only, then will the stash be a collection of commit objects, but in this case, just 1 commit object?  So if I modified 2 files, then 2 commit objects?  What about 1 file but 1 change at line 1 and 1 change at line 30, then... 1 commit object?  Or I guess I am trying to get at is, can we view it as... just an unnamed branch off, with all files committed... so we can "cherry-pick" this commit to apply the changes to any other situation?

Comment: by commit objects, you don't mean a complete commit?  that's because I know git will save a whole new file when you commit, so if I create a text file that is 15MB, with each line in it just 80 characters long with a line number, then if I edit the file for just 1 line and commit, the whole directory is now 15MB.  Change 1 line again and commit and now the whole directory is 30MB. Now if I make a new feature branch and switch there, edit 1 line, and do a `git stash`, the whole directory just increased a little bit in size (1MB or less).

Comment: (having said that... if I go back to the master branch, change another line and commit, the whole directory increased only a bit in size.  Maybe it is due to compression.)

Comment: Please distinguish "what is stored" and "how it is stored". Whenever you perform a commit, git stores a commit object in its object database, i.e. you can later recover the whole state at that commit. In practice, this is stored using delta-compression which saves your disk space (but delta-compression is not always applied, you need to run `git gc` or wait for git to run `git gc --auto` for you to get it).

Comment: BTW, one "commit object" is created when you commit (or stash, or ...), but a single commit contains the whole project state, regardless of how many files your modified since last commit.

Comment: by the way, do you have any reference that a stash is a collection of commit objects (vs a collection of diffs)? Isn't it true that a commit object can represent a whole file (a complete file with all the content)?  If so, why do we need this complete content... it seems a stash is mainly useful for "applying the diffs" again like cherry-picking a commit

Comment: Just check by yourself: launch `gitk --all` after running `git stash`, and play with `git cat-file -p` to see the types of objects. A commit object does not represent just the content of a *file*: it contains meta-data (date, log message, parents, ... and the content of the whole repository : a tree object in Git's terminology).

Answer (score 1):

[`man git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) says the following, under `pop` (which also applies to `apply`):

> The working directory must match the index.

So you are correct, it can apply the collection of diffs to `foo.txt`, but not if you have *unstaged* local changes. If you're confused about the difference between the working directory and the index, perhaps [this answer](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) can help.

Run `git add hei.txt`, and you will be able to apply the stash.

Comment: so I think the phrase "The working directory must match the index" means that everything must be staged? (or every tracked file must be staged?) Is there really a reason they have to be staged... except the fact that the man page says so? (that is... aside from what the man page says, is there really a good reason for requiring so?)

Comment: @太極者無極而生 git must know about your local changes (ie. they must be staged to the index) for it to be able to resolve conflicts. When you stage, git creates a ref (which you can see in `git reflog`). When you apply the stash, git merges the stash ref with the index ref. This also works as a safety net in that you can't lose local changes if the stash does something you didn't intend, because git knows about your changes.